# MD5 hash cracker lags out windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, md5, hashlib

So i have atempted to make bruteforce hash caracke on python but it lags out system for some reason
it works fine when range start value set to 1 but i have't tested what hapens when it goes up to 7.
So i am curious how can i make it run on longer words.
If posible with out anything complicated.

```
from hashlib import md5
import itertools
hash_to_crack = '7d02177d25987b26bc6f0738027253c3'
alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
found = False
print("Cracking...")
for i in range(7,9):
    if found:
        break
    words = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i)]
    for x in words:
        print(x)
        h = md5(x.encode("utf-8"))
        if hash_to_crack == str(h.hexdigest()):
            print("Found")
            print(x)
            found = True
            break
```

Comment: Brute force iteration on hard problems is like that.  Compare 10 ^ 1 vs. 10 ^ 7 on your calculator.  The fix is to use a better algorithm if one exists.  For example by  finding ways to skip some work like Sieve of Eratosthenes does for prime numbers.  Sometimes there is even a shortcut like for finding the sum of 1...N.

Comment: As @DaveS noted, you're doing a lot of work: 26**8 is simply a very, very big number. Here are a few speed improvements that are possible: 1) make alphabet a bytes object, and thereby avoid the call to `x.encode()` completely. 2) `itertools.product` outputs an iterator, so make the for loop read from this iterator and do the `b''.join(...)` inside this loop. 3) itertools.product outputs the string using an "odometer" type loop. That means for 26 consecutive words in a row only the last character differs. Precompute the md5 state on all but the last char, and clone and update it 26 times.